# Why can't I use a specified port in /etc/ssh/sshd_config for remote transfers?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, ubuntu-14.04, vps

I have  just setup a vps server on Ubuntu 14.04, for security reasons, I changed the allowed port for ssh connections in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

So far I've been able to connect remotely via this new port, but every time I try doing other remote connections with scp, rsync even after specifying the right port in the command, most times I get a response `Connection to Port 22 refused`.

I changed the port back to 22 and I was able to use scp and rsync fine so I'm guessing this commands use the Port 22 by default, how do I make this commands work with a different port?

Comment: You must  specify the port you want to connect to explicitly, in scp: *scp -P TheNewPort file1 username@remotehost:/home/username*. Ditto with rsync.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a way to configure the default port for scp, but you can define the port number to be used with the -P flag.

```
scp -P 9001 user@hostyyz:/path/to/file filetocopy
```

Comment: I get a response in shell that the connection has timed out. Thrice.

Comment: Use whatever port you're configuring  for ssh. 9001 is just an example.

Comment: Hi, Alex, does it matter that I have a port number of 61995? I can't get scp to work via this port.

Comment: The port's valid so it shouldn't be an issue. You can use SSH on the non-default port you've specified in sshd_config, and still use scp on 22. Doesn't that work?